# Number of divisors of $ 20^{20} $ with exactly $20$ divisors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> How many positive integers $x$ with  $x\mid 20^{20}$ have exactly $20$ divisors ?

Comment: Hint : The number is equal to the number of the divisors of $20$ (Try to find out why!)

Comment: You might say that's a "perfect" hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $20^{20}=2^{40}5^{20}$, the general form of such a factor is $2^a5^b$ for non-negative integers $a,\,b$ with $(a+1)(b+1)=20$. Note in particular the ordered pair $(a,\,b)$ is what matters, not the unordered pair $\{a,\,b\}$. There are exactly as many of these as there are factors of $20=2^25$, i.e. $3\times2=6$.